# Spring 4.2.1 is throwing ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager with Ehcache 3, JSR-107

Tags: spring, ehcache

I am trying to use [EHCache](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ehcache/ehcache/3.1.0) -3.0.2 with Spring 4.2.1 using [Jcache](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0) -1.0.0 but getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager`

I see in spring [EhCacheCacheManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context-support/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheCacheManager.java) is setting up CacheManager is type of net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager which is not available in EHCache 3.0. EHChcache has type of org.ehcache.CacheManager.

Seems if I use Spring then I will have to lower down EHCache version, which I don't want.

Please suggest me if there is any workaround or will have to wait until Spring Introduce it.

I was following [EHCache3+Spring4.2](http://www.ehcache.org/blog/2016/05/17/ehcache3_jsr107_spring.html) but seems it also has same issue.

Comment: How you using Jcache ?? I tried the tutorial GIT link project & its working with both Ehcache 3.0.0 & 3.0.2 libraries.

Comment: Only difference , I see that I am not using spring boot.

Comment: Please add an example of your integration. you should use the JCache integration, not the Ehcache one since that is limited to version 2.x

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that spring-context-support expects the Ehcache's CacheManager to be on this classpath: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager

However, in Ehcache 3, the CacheManager class resides on another classpath: org.ehcache.CacheManager.

So, basically spring-context-support does not support Ehcache 3. And you would have to use the JSR-107 annotations directly, not the annotations provided by Spring.

Comment: For more information on the topic, check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39386830/838608