# Using ehcache 3 with Spring Annotations (not using Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-4, jsr107

I'm trying to get Ehcache 3 working with Spring 4 without using Spring boot.

[Here is a working example out there which uses Spring Boot](http://www.ehcache.org/blog/2016/05/18/ehcache3_jsr107_spring.html), but I'm working on an existing application which is not using Spring Boot.

The problem is that spring-context-support (which adds Spring's cache annotations) expects the Ehcache's CacheManager to be on this classpath: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager

However, in Ehcache 3, the CacheManager class resides on another classpath: org.ehcache.CacheManager.

So, basically spring-context-support does not support Ehcache 3. And you would have to use the JSR-107 annotations directly, not the annotations provided by Spring.

But apparently it works with Spring Boot. Perhaps there is a way to make it work with a standard Spring Application as well. That's what I'm hoping. I really want to be using Spring's own annotations instead of the JSR-107 annotations.

Comment: Use the proper ehcahce 3 version, the one that is supported.

Comment: Which one is that? Thanks!

Comment: Just readig it again. When using ehcache3 you have to use the jcache abstraction with Spring (you still can use the spring annotation but for configuration you have to use the jcache factories). Else use ehcache2. My mistake sorry.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. I'll let you know later how it goes.

Comment: Interested to know where you got the link to the article? It can still be reached from http://www.ehcache.org/blog/ but there seems to be a 'date' difference in the URL for some reason ...

Comment: @LouisJacomet I got the article link from a google search two days ago (September 7). Then when I accessed it the next day, it was broken. (Double checked my browser's history)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed there is no native support of Ehcache 3 in Spring Caching.

The good news is that you achieve what you want with the [JCache support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-store-configuration-jsr107) that Spring Caching has since Ehcache 3 is a [compliant JCache implementation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.1/107.html).
And once you have a JCache `CacheManager` available in your application context, nothing forces you to use the JCache annotations. You can keep using the Spring Caching ones without any problem.

You can find a demo of that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSpgLZ1U75g).

Note: I am working on Ehcache

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up, that talk was really helpful! One of the things I did wrong in my setup was typing my caches in my Ehcache 3 configuration. Then when Spring's JCacheCacheManager called getCache(cacheName) on the underlying CacheManager (in my case Eh107CacheManager), it ended up throwing IllegalArgumentException: Cache [cacheName] specifies key/value types. Use getCache(String, Class, Class).

Comment: +1, I also encounter this problem, I think this is a bug(or maybe a not supported feature) that use Ehcache3.x in Spring, we can't define the "key-type" and "value-type" property in the ehcache.xml

Comment: Is it possible to use Ehcache3 with Spring ACL ?

Comment: @Sharadr have you tried with spring ACL? Did it worked?

Answer (score 4):

This is simple and working sample for all needed changes from ehcache 2 to 3: https://imhoratiu.wordpress.com/2017/01/26/spring-4-with-ehcache-3-how-to/

This this is link for new configuration:

- http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.4/xml.html
- http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.1/107.html#supplement-jsr-107-configurations